# задача на матрицу в паскаль

Tags: pascalabc.net

> Дана матрица вещественного типа G(8,6). Разработайте программу, которая заменяет все элементы исходной матрицы G на последнюю цифру в их записи. Выведите на экран полученную матрицу.

```
program kr_1;
  const m=8; n=6;
     var
   a: array[1..m,1..n] of real;
    i,j: byte;
 begin
randomize;
 writeln('матрица G');
 for i:=1 to m do
begin
for j:=1 to n do
begin
 a[i,j]:=random(50);
 write(a[i,j]:4);
 end;
writeln;
end;
 end.
```

Comment: Ну вот последнюю цифру числа Вы получить можете?

Answer (score 0):

```
##
var G := MatrGen(8, 6, (i,j) -> Random(-9999, 9999)/100);
Writeln('Исходная матрица:');
G.Print;
Writeln;
Writeln('Результирующая матрица:');
G.Transform(x -> real(x.ToString.Last.ToDigit));
G.Print(4,0)
```

[image: Пример работы]

Answer (score -1):

```
## // PascalABC.NET 3.6.3
Writeln('Исходная матрица G');
var G := new real[8, 6];
G.Transform(t -> real(Random(-99, 99)));
G.Println(4,0);
Writeln('Результирующая матрица G');
G.Transform(t -> real(Trunc(Abs(t)) mod 10));
G.Print(4,0)
```

[image: Скрин]